# checkins/recent not returning comments or even counts of comments

Tags: foursquare

My application has been using the checkins/recent endpoint to show where all the current users friends are currently at and I had included a button the user could press to comment on a checkin. The button used to have the comment count on it until recently.

It seems the checkins/recent endpoint no longer returns comments or even a comment count for those checkins. I would have to query each checkin in order to get the comment count which adds to the data usage not to mention API usage counts.

Is there another way to do this that I'm not seeing? Could you please at least put the comment count back? You have the photo information, why not comments?

Thanks

EDIT: Sorry, I found an old post in the google groups where I kinda asked the same thing, so I'm mistaken, comment counts were never returned before, but like I mentioned last time, it would be nice if at least the count was returned so it can be used in our apps in the manner mentioned above without another api call for each checkin.

Answer (score 0):

The checkins/recent endpoint does not return comment counts. You will have to query each checkin individually to get the comment data.

Comment: But it would be great if it did. Why doesn't it? Photo data is returned, why not comment data, at the very least the count??? This requirement to query each checkin just wastes a users data plan and eats into rate limits for something that could be returned so easily with checkins/recent.